# special characters display proper in Java IDE, but not in program launched from jar file

Tags: java, character-encoding, jar, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build a Chinese flashcards program in Java to help myself learn Chinese. I'm using intelliJ IDEA 10. The basic process is that my program will read a file saved on the local machine to generate the flashcards. The file is written using the File class in java. When opened in notepad, it displays all characters properly.

When I run it in the IDE I am able to display Chinese characters as well as pinyin characters(basically vowels with accent marks over them). However, when I built a jar file and launch the program from there, it can no longer display special characters and ends up showing a bunch of weird symbols.

Any ideas on why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ doesn't use the platform default encoding, it [autodetects](http://jetbrains.dzone.com/articles/new-approach-encoding) it based on the encoding of the source files. When running the code outside IntelliJ, you need to ensure that you explicitly specify the proper encoding when reading/writing the file. You can do that by specifying it as 2nd constructor argument of [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) respectively.

```
File file = new File("/foo.txt");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
// ...

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

Further you also need to ensure that the viewer supports the fonts as well. Windows Command Console for example, doesn't support Chinese. You'd need to create a Swing application to present the results instead.

Comment: This was the problem. The only thing I noticed while implementing your solution is that you have a slight typo. It should be

new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"); 

Essentially, it's moving an end parenthesis so that the "UTF-8" is a parameter of the InputStreamReader class. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. You're right about the typo, I fixed it. I am too much getting used to the form of `new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8")` :)

Comment: Windows doesn't suppoert UTF-8?  Please tell me you're kidding! That is an offensive joke if it is false, and even moreso if it is true.

Comment: @tchrist: I see that I didn't write what I actually meant. I reworded a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an encoding issue?

The `File` class doesn't have any methods for writing data to files. For that you need a `FileOutputStream` or some `Writer`. You should post your code that saves the file. (Just edit the question and add your code there.)

My first guess is that you use a `FileWriter`. This sounds easy, but it is often wrong, because the `FileWriter` needs to convert characters into bytes, and it does that with *the System's default encoding*. You should always specify the encoding yourself, and probably `UTF-8` is a good choice.

So instead of the `FileWriter` you should use the following code:

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
  Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os, utf8);
  wr.write("whatever strings you want to write");
  wr.close();
} finally {
  os.close();
}
```